# ¿Existe la forma de cambiar el idioma de Pycharm Edu 3.0 a español?

Tags: pycharm

Me gustaría saber si existe la forma de cambiar el idioma de Pycharm Edu 3.0 a español, trabajo con niños y se les complica bastante el idioma inglés puesto que no es su idioma natural.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que preguntas con el desarrollador del producto, en alguna de sus páginas de contacto:

- La página del soporte: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us
- Los foros de la comunidad: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200379535-PyCharm
- La página de ayuda: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/meet-pycharm.html
- Facebook: https://www.facebook.com/JetBrains
- Google+: https://plus.google.com/+jetbrains
- Twitter: https://twitter.com/jetbrains